# angular material error shows on the input field

Tags: angularjs, ng-animate, angularjs-material

i am use sample angular material input (on dialog)

```
<md-input-container flex="50">
         <label>Client Name</label>
         <input required name="clientName" ng-model="user.name">
         <div ng-messages="editForm.clientName.$error">
           <div ng-message="required">This is required.</div>
         </div>
       </md-input-container>
```

but when the error message disappear its appear for second on the input  and break the design  and not only under  the input (for example on start there is an error in good place only on change)

how can I fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution :

```
md-input-container .md-input-message-animation{ margin-top: 2px !important; }
```